# Register app in Azure AD to access CDS Web API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, common-data-service

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate an external app with Microsoft CDS Web API. The first step would be to try the Wep API with Postman. Following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment) I could authenticate and make requests to the API using the client id provided in the document. However, when I try to register my own app in my AAD, I can't get the access token in Postman without having first to request the admin for consent.

I followed the instructions in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory#create-an-application-registration) to register the app, plus I allowed implicit flow. A did this in a trial account, where I'm the admin and then I tried retrieving the token with an user of another tenant (where I'm not an admin) it tells me to ask the tenant for consent.

Do you know how to register the app without non-admin users having to request admin consent?

**Edit:**
The registrated app has the following permissions, where none of them require admin consent:
[Screenshot of the selected permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnhxp.png)

The tenant which the non admin-users belong to has the following configuration for users being able to consent access:
[Screenshot of user settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLpom.png)

Anyway, I assume these last settings would not be the problem because when requesting the token with the client id provided by Microsoft in the example of the first link, I do not require the consent from the admin.

Just for the sake of clarity, this is the step that I would like to remove from the authorization process:
[Screenshot of the consent request screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzzuF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know that not all permissions require admin consent.

`Dynamics CRM user_impersonation` permission doesn't require admin consent.

[image]

But you need to make sure all the permissions added into your registered app don't require admin consent. As long as any permission requires admin consent, then admin consent cannot be bypassed.

Besides, make sure this configuration has been abled in the tenant(which the non-admin users are from).

[image]

**UPDATE:**

You are correct. After testing, I found that this permission does require admin consent. I believe this is an error in the documentation. It seems that the conclusion is that we cannot bypass admin consent.

Comment: Allen, thanks for your detailed reply. My setting seems to fulfill those conditions (see my edit on the original post with screenshots, but admin consent is still being requested, even though it doesn't ask it for the sample client id provided by Microsoft.

Comment: and what about the app whose client id is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/setup-postman-environment)? It allows me to access the CDS Web API and does not request admin consent. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @PedroRosa Do you mean `51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d`? You are using Implicit flow?

Comment: Yes, I mean that client id. I've tried both Implicit and Authorization code, and the outcome is the same: Example app works, mine asks for consent

Comment: @PedroRosa `51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d` is an internal registered app which is designed for multi-tenant with some configurations which are not exposed. So I have no idea about it. But I'm sure if we create our own Azure AD app, admin consent is necessary currently.